# Initializing popover (bootstrap 4) within typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, popover

Was curious if anyone could help with this.
What I am trying to do is initialize popover and each data-toggle="popover" that is found using querySelectorAll().

Using typescript for this as well.

```
export class Popover {
   init() {
     let popoverList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle="popover"]');  

     let item = popoverList[i];
     // I thought than doing something like this would work but there is probably more to it any ideas?
     item.popover();
   }
}
```

Is something like what I am doing possible in some way?
Or is jQuery required to initialize popover?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, jQuery is required. Here's one of the options:

```
$(() => {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```